# PHP Block parsing mixed with HTML

Tags: php, html

I have some code that was working. I wanted to abstract a repeated part into a function, so I did so, but now I have two issues. The first is that when I put the definition of my function `courseSet` lower in the file than the call, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function courseSet()

I thought that it doesn't matter where a function is defined because the entire PHP file is parsed before it's run?? After failing to get this working, I decided to give up and move the function into the same PHP block above the call. Now, I get a different error. At the top of my code I define the database variable, `$db`. In my function, I have a line `global $db;` before that variable is invoked in the function. Based on my understanding of PHP scoping, I should then be able to execute my next line (`$db->setQuery(...);`, but I got another error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setQuery() on null

The relevant part of my code:

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO(); //Get Database Object
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dettagli</legend>
        <p>
            Nome e Cognome:<br>
            <input type="text" name="nome">
        </p>
        <p>
            Organizzazione:<br>
            <input type="text" name="organizzazione">
        </p>
        <p>
            Numero di partecipanti:<br>
            <input type="number" name="num_part" min="1">
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    <?php
        courseSet("IG");
        courseSet("IS");
        courseSet("PG");
        courseSet("BI");
        courseSet("IT");
    ?>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
    function fullCatName($categoria) {
        $categoria_name = "";

        switch ($categoria) {
            case "IG" :
                $categoria_name = "Informatica Generale";
                break;
            case "IS" :
                $categoria_name = "Informatica Specializzata";
                break;
            case "PG" :
                $categoria_name = "Progettazione Gestione";
                break;
            case "BI" :
                $categoria_name = "Business Intelligence";
                break;
            case "IT" :
                $categoria_name = "Impiantistica: Normativa e Nuove Tecnologie";
        }

        return $categoria_name;
    }

    function courseSet($categoria) {
        $cat_name = fullCatName($categoria);

        echo "<fieldset><legend>Corsi: ".$cat_name."</legend>";

        global $db;
        $db->setQuery("SELECT DISTINCT titolo FROM Corsi WHERE `categoria` = '$categoria'");
        $result = $db->loadColumn();
        foreach($result as $key => $value){
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='corso[]' value='".$result[$key]."''>".$result[$key]."<br>";
        }

        echo "<br></fieldset>";
    }
?>
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong! Thanks.

Comment: can you please show your code? otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: please move your code into your question and remove the 3rd party link

Comment: You've already figured out the first part: the function must be declared before you can use it. The second is that `$db` does not exist within the scope of the function, or the connection failed.

Comment: @aynber is this really true also for functions? Not in my test I just did because I wonderd... (of course yes for vars, constants,..)

Comment: edited to show code. @aynber the connection shouldn't have failed because the code successfully connects to the database when not wrapped in a function. and re the first part the PHP documentation [states](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) that

> Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, except when a function is conditionally defined as shown in the two examples below.

Comment: @Jeff Actually, I may be wrong... But if it works one way and not the other... *shrug*

Comment: `if(!$db = JFactory::getDBO()){ echo 'error'; }`